# I can't find a translation for 言やいー

Tags: words, translation, meaning

I would very much appreciate it if someone could tell me what 言やいー refers to. All I know is that 言 has something to do with speaking or words, but that alone doesn't help. Is it slang?

The entire phrase I'm trying to decipher is: 食えないなら食えなんって言やいーのに

So far I only understand the parts about being unable to eat.

Comment: If it helps at all, you might want to look at [this entry](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%84%E3%81%84) on やい.  Just from the line given, it almost sounds like someone is telling someone else: *"if you can't eat (this), you could have just said so (in the first place)"*.  But... is there any way there could be more context given for this phrase?  And, welcome to the forum ^^

Comment: That makes sense, actually, given the context. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that this is a contraction of 言えばいい, similar to how it works in しなきゃ (ければ→きゃ). ～ばいいのに is a common phrase so I'm pretty sure this is correct.

I'm assuming also that 食えなんって is either a mistyping or a dialect with which I'm not familiar.

Comment: +1.  Searching on Google, I found pages backing up `〜えば` → `〜や`, for example on [Weblio](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E8%A8%80%E3%82%84).